# "Please return the equipment to its original place after being used."

Tags: sentence-construction

Are the following sentences accurate?

> 1. Please return the equipment to its original place after being used
> 2. Please return the equipment to its original place after use
> 3. Please return the equipment to its original place after using
> 4. Please return the equipment to its original place after it has been used

I feel like **"after being used"** is ambiguous here. Which construction would be correct and preferable among these??

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would change the order:

"After using, please return the equipment to its original place."

Alternatively, you could go with:

"When finished using the equipment, please return to its original place."

However if you want to maintain the original sentence structure, I would go with the second one:

"Please return the equipment to its original place after use."

You could also go with using, but then I think you should add some extra words:

"Please return the equipment to its original place after you've finished using it."

Comment: "When finished using the equipment, please return to its original place." You're missing "it" after "return".

Answer (score 0):

Examples 1 and 2 are slightly better than the others (but they still sound incomplete):

> 1. Please return the equipment to its original place after being used.
> 2. Please return the equipment to its original place after use

It would sound slightly better (to my ears, at least) to say:

> Please return the equipment to its original place **when you no longer need it**.

or

> Please return the equipment to its original place **when it is no longer needed**.

---

Example 3 is just incomplete, additional words are needed.

Example 4 it sounds plain wrong to me, associating "its" and "they".

Comment: could you please elaborate why the first one is better.